# Как отправлять данные с SQL Server в телеграм?

Tags: sql, sql-server, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет! Возможно ли как-то отправлять новые строки, которые появляются в таблице одной из БД SQL Server в телеграм?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо промежуточное программное обеспечение. Можете писать с нуля или воспользоваться существующими библиотеками. Вот пример клиента для c# https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot .
Если хотите более легкие варианты, то можно посмотреть в сторону Python. https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

Соответственно как источник данных для бота, можно подключить базу и настроить к ней необходимые ендпоинты.